# For-each inside another For-Each and access a attribute defined in the first loop using the value of the second

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xsl-fo

For-each of a collection of headers and find a certain attribute in another collection of Items. If I have something like:

```
<ROOT>  
  <Listings> 
    <Listing>
      <Headers>
        <Header width="3cm" value="UserName" />
        <Header width="3cm" value="MobileAlias" />
        <Header width="3cm" value="Name" />
        <Header width="3cm" value="Email" />
        <Header width="1cm" value="Gender" />
        <Header width="2cm" value="LastLoginDate" />
        <Header width="2cm" value="LastActivityDate" />
        <Header width="1.5cm" value="IsApproved" />
        <Header width="1.5cm" value="IsLockedOut" />
      </Headers>
      <Footers></Footers>
      <Items>
        <Item UserName="Admin" MobileAlias="Admin" Name="Systems Administrator" Email="388354123@foo.com" Gender="Male" LastLoginDate="29-07-2009 12:54:59" LastActivityDate="29-07-2009 12:56:37" IsApproved="True" IsLockedOut="False" />
        <Item UserName="Guest" MobileAlias="Guest" Name="Anonymous User" Email="1516626590@foo.com" Gender="Male" LastLoginDate="" LastActivityDate="" IsApproved="True" IsLockedOut="False" />
      </Items>
    </Listing>
  </Listings>
</ROOT>
```

---

How can I get something like:

```
  <fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Admin</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Admin</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>System Administrator</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>388354123@foo.com</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>Male</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>29-07-2009 12:54:59</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>29-07-2009 12:56:37</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>True</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell><fo:block>True</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
  </fo:table-row>
  (...)
```

I mean, for-each Item in Items, for-each Header in Headers, return the attribute Header@value from Item

Much appreciated.

Comment: I would go for 'Tomalak' solution because of the clean/template solution but you were always the first :D

Truly a life saver since I was banging my head to the wall all afternoon. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using separate templates for increased maintainability. The following is basically what AnthonyWJones did, but adapted to your input:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
>

  <xsl:output method='xml' indent="yes" /> 

  <!-- <Listing> elements become tables -->
  <xsl:template match="Listing">
    <fo:table>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- <Items> elements become table rows -->
  <xsl:template match="Items">
    <fo:table-row>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- applies the correct order to the output -->
  <xsl:template match="Item">
    <fo:table-row>
      <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
      <xsl:for-each select="../../Headers/Header">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$this/@*[name() = current()/@value]" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- <Item> attributes become table cells -->
  <xsl:template match="Item/@*">
    <fo:table-cell>
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1. ... but yours gets the actual job done is a better approach for a real solution. ;)

Comment: The best of both worlds. The solution and the templates.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know xsl-fo but that isn't relevant.  Here is a simple example generating a HTML table:-

```
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
  <table rules="all">
    <xsl:for-each select="Listings/Listing/Items/Item">
      <xsl:variable name="item" select="." /> 
      <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Listings/Listing/Headers/Header">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$item/@*[local-name()=current()/@value]" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```